# Access to window.scrollY in Server Side Rendering, is that possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

Is it possible to have an access to window dynamic events when rendering from server side (it is express app)?

I would like to follow user's scrolling in dynamic manner. I need that to create an infinite scroll (increment pagination based on scroll position), but this time in the SSR.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible on the backend(server side) to have access to the browser events/data without sending them manually to the backend.

The first thing which comes to my mind is to send the scroll's position by an Ajax request or use WebSockets - depending on the expected frequency of the send operations.

In your case, you can send current scroll position by an Ajax request and depending on the value of the position, send new content to the client and render it.